# Keydown number bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i use simple input not with bootstrap 3, everyyhin is working ok

**HTML**

```
   <input id="inputOffice" type="text" name="office" '/>
```

**JS**

```
$("#inputOffice").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/v1vvw7ux/

But when I use a same code in bootstrap 3 it does not work, here is all with bootstrap 3

http://www.bootply.com/y4VvkKX3PO

Please try in fullscreen preview?

I dontk know why it does not working ok, maybe it is a problem with jquery version, can some one check, please?

Comment: It accepts only numbers. Is that the desired output? Both works the same for me in Chrome 37!

Comment: Please try full screen preview

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 37 as well, but does not work in IE 11

Comment: No difference! Works well! :)

Comment: Does not work in Mozzila also :(

Comment: When I remove the comments, it works fine. Bootply interpreter may have issues here with comments in between JS statements.

Comment: You have a stray apostrophe in your `input` tag